# Why is Android Studio not recognizing my custom vmoptions file?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I need a custom vmoptions file for my Android Studio 3.0 installation on Windows. I'm setting the environment variable **STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS** as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html). While this seems to work when launching **studio.exe**, it fails to work when launching **studio64.exe**.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the environment variable **STUDIO64_VM_OPTIONS**.  This is similar to how the JetBrains' IDEs work.  Unfortunately Android's documentation does not mention anything about this.  There is an [open issue with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72153828) to add the missing information.